# Apache Module mod_auth_digest

Tags: apache

I'm trying to  configure my server to use the Apache Module mod_auth_digest directive only am having a tough time. Here's what I've got:

```
htdigest -c passwdfile registered_users@mydomain.net andy
```

'passwdfile' resides in

```
/var/www/
```

and in my httpd.conf file

```
<Location /var/www/mydomain/wp-admin/>
  AuthType Digest
  AuthName "private area"
  AuthDigestDomain /var/www/mydomain/wp-admin/ 

  AuthDigestProvider file
  AuthUserFile /var/www/passwdfile
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

both mod_authn_file & mod_auth_digest are present on my server. Upon browsing to

http://mydomain.net/wp-admin I'm expecting to be prompted by Apache for a username and password only am not!

Answer (score 0):

The location directive maps to the request URI not a server path.

Change

```
<Location /var/www/mydomain/wp-admin/>
```

To

```
<Location /wp-admin>
```

See docs here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location

Comment: thanks, I'm now prompted for username and password. Entering my credentials and it simply won't let me in. I've tried using FF and Chromium browsers.

Comment: auth digest can be somewhat convoluted at first. Try to create a simple user and password first, get it working then create more complex combinations. Also check the passwdfile to make sure your username/password combo exists.

Comment: @ Rijndael, It now works, thanks again. Must have been something to do with the cache.